# Property of a number that allows it to evolve in varying circumstances?

Tags: logic

It is kind of hard to explain precisely what I am seeking and I am using the word "number" loosely.  Is there a property in mathematics or a mathematical object that can have different properties under different constraints or in different circumstances? Ie.  Could this symbol I will call it Ѯ (a symbol I chose at random) be for example odd in some circumstances, even in others, prime in others, have a probability of being a particular number for example if I chose the set (137, 42, 118, 0183) could it be each one with a probability of one quarter or could it have a weighted probability based on its value?  (ie 137 would have a higher probability than 42 if probabilities were assigned by the weight of magnitude but would have a lower probability if weights were assigned by other properties like how 42 is even).

Answer (score 1):

One example of what you might be looking for is the different, so called, rings which exist. For instance if we look at the ring $(Z,+,\cdot)$ i.e. the integers equipped with addition and multiplication we have a unit element $1$ for multiplication. What we mean by that is that $1\cdot x= x$ for each $x\in Z-\{0\}$. However $5$ does not have an inverse, in the sence that no integer $y\in Z$ is such that $5\cdot y=1$.

However if we look at it in a different circumstance i.e. in the ring $(Q,+,\cdot)$ the rational numbers together with addition and multiplication, then still $1$ will be a unit element, however now suddenly $5$ has an inverse in our base set $Q$ namely the element $1/5$. That is we see that $5 \cdot 1/5 = 1$.
In fact every $x\in Q-\{0\}$ has a multiplicative inverse $1/x$ among the numbers in $Q$ while no element in $Z-\{0,1\}$ has a multiplicative inverse in $Z$. So here we have a clear example of objects which in different context have different properties.

When it comes to randomness you should look at [Random Variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) who I think can represent exactly what you want in your example with the set $\{137,42,118,0183\}$. The classic example with a random variable is to let the variable $X$ represent the result of a thrown 6-sided dice. Thus with probability $1/6$ the $X$ will have the values $4$. We may modify this example easily and give a weight to the dice so that getting $4$ has probability $1/2$ while each of the other numbers have probability $1/10$.

I would claim that in general this is true for most concepts and objects. There are extensions, circumstances and special cases where certain properties hold and where the do not. This is true for things from differentiability to being prime or divisible. You probably should look into abstract algebra if you are interested, where I think these concepts are readily explored in its abstractness and you really try to figure out "what does it really mean for a number to be (for instance prime)".